# as you will - meaning

Tags: meaning, as

Source: [**How Russia Is Revolutionizing Information Warfare**](https://www.defenseone.com/threats/2014/09/how-russia-revolutionizing-information-warfare/93635/) (news article)

> “We’re an empire now, and when we act, we create our own reality. And while you’re studying that reality—judiciously, **as you will**—we’ll act again, creating other new realities, which you can study too, and that’s how things will sort out. We’re history’s actors … and you, all of you, will be left to just study what we do.”

Does the phrase **as you will** mean something like *if you will*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*...as you will* **does not** mean *if you will.* In such structure, it means the listener is going to study that reality (judiciously). ***As you see,*** I have used the similar way of saying that!

Rephrase that sentence and it shapes up like this -

> “We’re an empire now, and when we act, we create our own reality. And while you’re studying that reality—judiciously, as you will *(study that reality, judiciously)*, we’ll act again, creating other new realities, which...

Answer (score -2):

**As you will** means **as you wish** and it is used to express obedience.

```
You may do as you will, but that does not mean your actions will be right.
```

Comment: It can mean that, but not in this context.