# as was previously hoped all but 10 years ago - meanig of "all but" in this context?

Tags: grammar

Source: http://www.inquisitr.com/1467926/world-war-3-russias-nuclear-weapons-fired-vladimir-putin-warns-u-s-of-more-corresponding-countermeasures/

> Unfortunately, Russia’s nuclear bombs are increasing in number, not decreasing as was previously hoped **all but** 10 years ago.

What does that mean in this context?

Comment: It means *just* or *only* meaning it wasn't that long ago.

Comment: It's *bad English* - same as "as you will" in [your earlier question](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/33146/). In the unlikely event that the writer specifically wanted to convey that the earlier optimism was ***very slightly less** than 10 years ago* he should have used ***almost***. But I would say that's extremely unlikely - what he almost certainly meant to say was something more like *as **had been hoped a mere** 10 years ago* (the word "previously" also looks more like a bad translation than something a native speaker would include here).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before coming to your sentence, let's look at the general usage of "*all but*".

[Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/all%20but) defines "all but" as:

> **all but** *adverb*
>
> : very nearly   Full Definition of ALL BUT
>
> :  *very nearly* :  *almost*
>
> **Examples of ALL BUT**
>
> *- Without you the job would have been all but impossible.* (Here **all but** implies something like- *without you the job would have been **almost** impossible*).
>
> *- We had all but given up hope.* (Again, this means- *we had **almost/very nearly** given up hope.* A simple way of saying this would- *we were on the verge of giving up hope.*)

---

As Frank pointed out, "***all but***" can be used in another sense to imply ***"everything except"*** or ***"all except"*** the one that is mentioned.

Looking at some examples of this usage:

> **All but** the weakest plants survived the hot weather.
>
> (Here, all but serves the purpose of implying that all the plants survived the hot weather, **except** the weak ones.)
>
> From [TheFreeDictionary.com](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/all+but)

---

Now, putting the meaning of "all but" in your sentence:

> Unfortunately, Russia’s nuclear bombs are increasing in number, not
> decreasing as was previously hoped all but 10 years ago.

Here *all but 10 years ago* means **only just 10 years ago**. All but is intended to give the impression that the period(10 years) wasn't that long ago.

Comment: +1 It would be even better to mention the _all but [something]_ use that means _everything except [something]_ so that both meanings of _all but_ are clear to anyone else reading the answer.

Comment: Thanks, Frank, for pointing that out. Made the necessary edits.

Comment: Nice. If I could +1 again I would.... maybe somewhere else then.